# Google Apps Script - Mysterious comma on value from Google Form / Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This is my scenario:

I have a Google Form, and the values are added to a SpreadSheet. I have an Apps Script started with `function onFormSubmit(event)`

I get the values from the Form with `var Variable = event.namedValues["Question 1"];`
I use the value of this variables with some "if statements".

This Apps Script has been running OK, but i'm still making changes to add new functionalities (adding more questions on the Form, new functions on the Script), but suddenly in one of the variables starts to appear a comma into the values from this variable.

After checking all the Script, i decided to copy all the script to a new one. And when I used this new scenario (same content of files), the mysterious comma disappeared. I continued with new developments, but after some new changes (newer ones) the comma started to appear on one of the variables in their values. And after some new changes the comma moved from adding at the begging of the value, started to appear at the end.

I have checked the values on the spreadsheet, and they appear with no comma, the comma only appears when i use the values of that variable on the script.
I print the value with `Logger.log(Variable)` after i save the value from the event, and the comma is there, so i don't think that my code is adding this comma.

Any idea why is this happening? Is there a way to check on the value of a variable a character (in this case the comma) inside the Script? Something like `Replace(Variable,",","")`, with this i can check all the values got from the event before i start using them inside the Script. Commas aren't used on the values of the variables.

THESE ARE THE LINES AFFECTED (The script has more than 500 lines):

```
function onFormSubmit(event){
  var Variable = event.namedValues["Question 1"];
  Logger.log("Value after event" + Variable);
    
  if (Variable == "AAAA"){
    // do "something";
  }
  else {
    // do "something different"
  }
}
    
As the comma appears the if statement never gets a TRUE because the value starts to be "AAAA," so the do "something" never happens.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answers:

1. Any idea why is this happening?

   - There might be some typos out there that needs to be cleaned. It would be better if you could also provide your code or at least how you wrote it.
2. Is there a way to check on the value of a variable a character (in this case the comma) inside the Script?

   - You can check the presence of a character/string in a variable by using `includes`.

```
var string = "I am Iron man,";
var hasComma = string.includes(","); // True
```

If you want to replace all the instances of comma, then use `replace`

```
// Replace all commas with blank
var string = string.replace(",", ""); // "I am Iron man"
```

#### EDIT:

Since `e.namedValues["Question 1"]` returns an object, you need to change the variable into string and then use the `replace` function

#### Code:

```
var Variable = e.namedValues["Question 1"];
Variable = String(Variable).replace(",", "");
  
Logger.log("Value after event: " + Variable);

if (Variable == "AAAA"){
  // do "something";
}
else {
  // do "something different";
}
```

#### References:

- [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)
- [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NaziA.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Alvaro, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I have edited my original post with some pseudocode. I can't use function replace. Variable is created `var Variable = event.NamedValues["Question"]` if i try to use `Variable.replace(",","");`it say TypeError is not a function. i've tried to do `Variable.tostring();` between the event and the replace commands, but get the same error.

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, I have updated my answer, kindly test. You need to type cast `Variable` into string and use the replace function. It should look like this: `String(Variable).replace(",", "");`

Comment: I have found the problem, in the Form i have put 2 questions with the same title in different places (is a conditional form based on previous answers).

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, you can use `e.values` instead as only the order of the question will matter, not the title of the question. Question titles will be most likely changed, but the order of the questions should most likely remains the same, although, it isn't as much as readable compared to `namedValues`

Comment: But if I use 'e.values', i will get an array of values, so i have to get de value using the position of the array,  is that correct? if so, this command will be order dependant of the form, so if i reorder the questions from the form, i have to update the command to point to the new position (and many of them will need an update).

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, If that's the case then I agree with you, `e.values` would not be good in your issue.